# What is the name of the distribution of the maximum number of distinguishable balls in a single distinguishable box?

Tags: probability, statistics, balls-in-bins

Imagine that there are $k$ distinguishable balls and $n$ distinguishable boxes. Each ball is placed into a random box. Next we calculate the maximum number of balls in a single box, which will be a value between $\left \lceil \dfrac{k}{n}\right \rceil$, when the balls are distributed almost evenly, and $k$, all balls in one box. Let's call this $X_{k,n}$

- What distribution does $X_{k,n}$ follow?
- I've encountered a situation where $k$ is about $100,000$ and $n$ is about $100$. How could I estimate the CDF for these particular values? What is $\mathbb{P}(X_{k,n}<2000)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.